# MongoDB - Geospatial intersection performance

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization, geospatial, database-optimization

We are developing a small tool that will allow a person to draw a polygon on a Google Map, and it will return zip codes that overlap the drawn overlay(s).  I figured this would be a great time to dive into a NoSQL database, since I've heard great things about performance when dealing with large sets of data.

So I took all of the ZCTA (Zip Code Tabulation Area) shape data from the US Census 2010 data set and loaded it into a MongoDB as follows.  Sample document:

```
{ "ZipCode" : 12345,
  "Polygon" : { type : "Polygon",
                coordinates: [[[lng1, lat1],[lng2, lat2], ... , [lngN, latN]]]}}
```

I also have an index set on the Polygon column as follows:

```
db.ZipCodes.ensureIndex({"Polygon" : "2dsphere"})
```

Finally, I translate the points from the google polygon into another GeoJSON polygon, and query the data using $geoIntersects as follows:

```
db.<collection>.find( { "Polygon" :
                     { $geoIntersects :
                       { $geometry :
                         { type : "Polygon" ,
                           coordinates : [[[lng1,lat1], [lng2,lat2], ... , [lngN, latN]]]
                  } } } } )
```

This works great when the overlay polygon is small, but when the polygon spans, say, a couple of states (US), the query takes forever ( > 20 min!).  How can I bring this down to a more reasonable response time?  I have indexed the zip code polygons, and since that's all I'm querying against, I would assume this would be as optimized as it can be.  Am I indexing incorrectly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you.  I will look into these options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After tearing my hair out trying to figure out the best way to accomplish better performance in MongoDB, I decided to try our existing standard DB, SQL Server.  I guess my low expectations for SQL Server's geospatial functionality were unfounded.  The query ran in < 12 seconds without an index, and didn't scale up exponentially like MongoDB for larger drawn polygons.  After adding an index, most queries are in the 1 second range.

I guess I'll be sticking with what I know.  I really had high hopes for MongoDB, but geospatial performance is severely lacking (or severely under-documented on how to improve it).